# How can I use Cancan permissions to filter the papertrail versions that I retrieve for a timeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, paper-trail-gem

I have a few models with version changes I am tracking using Papertrail. I want to pull out the version for a timeline view of recent activity, but users should only see changes to models which they have permission to view.

I use Cancan to control access to all areas of the app, and the Ability class has all the business logic I need. However, it specifies the model name e.g. Post in the rulesets, whereas PaperTrail uses the Version model to store changes.

How can I (efficiently) tie the two systems together so that I can ask the DB to only return Version models where the associated model is visible to the user? I can do this by just getting the whole timeline of the whole site and looping over it in Ruby, but this is not scalable and I need to use scopes so that it happens in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

A `version` is also an ActiveRecord model. That means you can incorporate it into your Ability class. You can simply do `object.versions.accessible_by(current_ability)` after you've made sure your Ability properly authorizes versions.

An example could be:

```
can :read, Version do |version|
  ((version.item_type == 'Client') && (Client.find(version.item_id).account_manager_id == user.id)) ||
  ((version.item_type == 'Project') && (Project.find(version.item_id).allowed_users.map(&:id).include? user.id) )
end
```

This can, of course, be simplified by using `version.item`, but then you'll have to delegate the authorization check to another resource (which would enable you to simply say `can? :read, version.item`). This may or may not suit your specific situation. The method above provides more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks. I did consider something like this, but the drawback is that it would cause duplication, as the other models have several rules each, which would all need copying into the Versions rule. Better than nothing at all, of course, but it feels a bit messy.

Comment: You could also make versioning an action on a model, e.g. `can :version, Client`. But this won't enable you to use accessible_by on versions themselves.